# 3DES with AndroidKeyStore StrongBoxBacked crashes with Attempt to get length of null array when Cipher.init is called

Tags: android, android-keystore, 3des

I trying to insert 3DES key into AndroidKeyStore with `setIsStrongBoxBacked(true)` and then encrypt and decrypt some text. I understand that normal AndroidKeyStore dont support 3DES, but Hardware security module support Triple DES according this document https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#HardwareSecurityModule

this is my test code:

```
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
        keyStore.setEntry(
                "TestAlias",
                new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(kg.generateKey()),
                new KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setIsStrongBoxBacked(true)
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                        .build());
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey("TestAlias", null);
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        IvParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(c.getIV());
        byte[] encrypted = c.doFinal("hello, world".getBytes());
        c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        String decrypted = new String(c.doFinal(encrypted));
```

But it always crash on line `c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);` with

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
> at com.android.org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter.(KeyParameter.java:17)
> at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineInit(BaseBlockCipher.java:787)
> at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineInit(BaseBlockCipher.java:1153)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryTransformWithProvider(Cipher.java:2985)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher.tryCombinations(Cipher.java:2892)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher$SpiAndProviderUpdater.updateAndGetSpiAndProvider(Cipher.java:2797)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:774)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1144)
> at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1085)
> ....

I already tested AES instead 3DES and it complet without problems.

Testing on Pixel 6 with strongbox support.

Answer (score 0):

Was create key successful? Also, it seems that the code you’re using does not have BouncyCastle but the logs have bouncycastle. Am I missing something?

It is possible that you’re using previously created key with wrong provider later on.

Comment: Yes i think that key was created successfully, because it doesn't crash and getKey function doesn't returned null.

Comment: Also if i put "AndroidKeyStore" as provider to Cipher.getInstance it will than crash on init with Exception that AndrodiKeyStore don't support DESede algorithm. And i can't find antoher KeyStore that is used with strongbox backed keys on googles documentation.

Comment: I don’t think you are supposed to use AndroidKeystore as the provider for the code above. Since your KeyGenerator.getInstance is initialized with default provider, Cipher.getInstance should follow similar pattern i.e. default provider. Also you could try to change the alias and try again. If the key is already present then it might create some issues.

Comment: If i can´t use AndroidKeyStore, what keystore i must use if i want key to be inside hardware security module? If i use KeyStore.getDefaultType() which return "BKS" KeyStore.setEntry will throw "java.security.KeyStoreException: unsupported protection parameter". I tried every provider listed here https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore and everyone throw same exception as "BKS" except of "AndroidKeyStore".

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t clear there. You’ll definitely need to use ‘KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");’. However, your Cipher.getInstance does not require a provider.

Comment: What you are describing was my first attempt. Code and exception is in description of this issue.